# Zen Cart - Digital Download Updates

Tags: shopping-cart, zen-cart

Been using Zen Cart for digital downloads for years now. We recently started selling software that periodically gets it's version updated. I know the user can log back into their account and retrieve their downloads, but what's still being shown is the old version. How can I force the customer history of downloads to be updated when the zip file is updated, so that they can download the updated version?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution you are asking for, but it is the only easy solution I can think of:

1. List the new version as a product.
2. Create a discount coupon for the price of the new version and a restriction to allow only the purchase of that product.
3. Send the customers who bought the old version a mail with the coupon code and the url of the new version's product page.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggested way of doing it:

Theoretically:
The original purchased Filename: v1.product_download.pdf 
The new version is released, v2.product_download.pdf

1. Upload the v2.product_download.pdf file to your downloads directory and create your new product for the v2 product for future purchases.
2. For customers who already purchased v1 you will Update the SQL table to set the v2.product_download.pdf filename in the customer's order history like this:

> UPDATE orders_products_download SET orders_products_filename =
>   'v2.product_download.pdf' 
>       WHERE orders_products_filename = 'v1.product_download.pdf';

This assures existing customers have v2 in their order history, and v2 is a new product for sale to future customers. Of course, you'll want to disable the sale of v1 of the product so you don't have to deal with people asking for a free upgrade when they discover they bought v1 and should have bought v2.

Of course, you *will* perform a complete backup of your database before running *any* SQL scripts on your production website!

Then, send out your email to your customers who purchased v1.product_download.pdf, and instruct them to login and view their order history, and download the new v2.product_download.pdf.